# Setting username and password in proxy to access internet in android 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internet, proxy

I have Android 2.3.6.

I am able to connect to wireless connection. To access internet in this network, I need to provide a proxy (IP address with port) with username and password. In the advanced options, I am able to find `proxy_ip_add` and `proxy_port`, but not username and password. Because of this, I am not able to access internet.

How can I set the username and password in the proxy to access internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android only supports proxies with credentials in Android 4.0+.

In android 2.3 or below I recommend you use the [proxydroid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) to use the proxy. This app supports authenticated proxies but needs root access.

The reason you have a proxy setting could be due to additions by your device manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks.... I will install it soon on my device. Can you provide any web link about operating my android 2.3.6 as root?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Google your device name root.

Comment: Ok.... I got it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDSnObObbpA)

Thank you....